# Linux - IPC with init

Tags: init

The init process exists as an ancestor of all of processes on a linux system. Does this process have any kind of IPC entry point ? Do other processes ever do IPC with init for any reason ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't conflate processes and programs.  There's one process #1, but it can be running one of a number of different programs.

- If it is running the `systemd` program from the systemd package:

  - [There is an internal systemd API](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/dbus/) accessible via D-Bus, that is not guaranteed stable and not intended to be used by things outwith the systemd package.
  - [It responds to a large set of signals](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.html#Signals), ranging from `SIGWINCH` and `SIGPWR` to `SIGRTMIN + 4`.
- If it is running the [`system-manager`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/system-manager.xml) program from [the nosh package](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/):

  - It responds to a fairly large subset of the signals recognized by `systemd`, with the same meanings where applicable.
- If it is running the `init` program from upstart:

  - [There is an internal upstart API](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#controlling-upstart-using-d-bus), accessible via D-Bus.
  - It reads command messages from the `initctl` FIFO.
  - It responds to small set of signals.
- If it is running Joachim Nilsson's `finit`:

  - It reads command messages from the `initctl` FIFO.
  - It responds to [a small set of signals](https://github.com/troglobit/finit/blob/master/doc/signals.md).
- If it is running the System 5 `init` then:

  - It reads command messages from the `initctl` FIFO.
  - It responds to a very small set of signals.

Some notes:

- The signal API is mandated by the things that send the signals to process #1.  These include the operating system kernel, which sends things like `SIGWINCH`, `SIGINT`, and `SIGPWR`, and various widespread system utility programs.

  - Both `systemd` and the nosh `system-manager` extend this with signals that command system state changes (such as shutting down and powering off the system).
  - Not all programs document supporting the full set of system-mandated signals.  upstart makes no mention of responding to `SIGPWR`, for example.
  - `finit` recognizes a different set of non-system-mandated extended signals, including `SIGSTOP` and `SIGCONT`.
- Although the systemd package doesn't implement the `initctl` FIFO API in the program that runs as process #1, it does provide a *compatibility shim* in *another* process, running another program, that translates that mechanism onto native systemd mechanisms.  (The nosh toolset has its own [`initctl-read`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/initctl-read.xml) compatibility shim that similarly translated into the native mechanisms of the nosh toolset's system management.)

  - `initctl` really isn't native to anything but System V `init`, as the others (if they do so at all) only implement the notion of run levels as a limited backwards-compatibility mechanism.
  - As the upstart man page for its `init` program says, the `initctl` mechanism isn't well documented.  Even the System V `init` people go around telling people that only things in the System V `init` package should use it.  It doesn't help, moreover, that the Debian System V maintainers relocated it from `/dev` to `/run`.

So yes, programs do IPC with process #1.  Their reasons for doing so vary.

- The `systemd` program is a combination system manager, service manager, and control groups manager and so there are a lot of purposes for which programs employ IPC to process #1.  The same for upstart's `init`.
- For nosh's `system-manager`, conversely, *service* management is done by another program (`service-manager`) in another process with its own (daemontools-compatible) APIs.  So the only reason to do IPC with process #1 is for *system state* management, such as (say) rebooting the machine.

For many (not all) purposes, one is better off sticking to other APIs, using conventional system utilities to do things like shutdown and reboot the system, rather than sending the signals understood by the `system-manager` and `systemd` programs when they are running as process #1.

### Further reading

- https://superuser.com/questions/886825/

Comment: Actually I'm writing a daemon to work with a Raspberry Pi specific UPS add-on and I am using that `initctl` to tell `init` (*I'm not doing anything with that there new-fangled `systemd` thingy - at least not until it gets to be a lot more stable in extreme cases*) when the Main power has dropped and come back - and when to shut down because the battery is running critically low.  The intricacies are not that complex but I am using it because that is *exactly* what that API is intended for.

Comment: Thank you for the mention :)

Finit also supports UNIX domain socket IPC.