# Does anything USE /dev/initctl or /run/initctl

Tags: init, sysvinit, ups, nut

[I have been investigating code for a UPS for a Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/39457/how-does-init-get-to-know-about-power-events) that is using sysv init rather than systemd (personal preference and familiarity).  I was looking into how a privileged script - possibly part of or run from /etc/rc.local - would tell init that there was *a shortage of electrons in the power supply system*.  The `init(8)` man page tells me about writing a single capital letter ('F'ailing,'O'k or critically 'L'ow) into formerly `/etc/powerstatus` but now `/var/run/powerstatus` and then sending `init` a `SIGPWR` signal; but there is the warning that:

> Usage of `SIGPWR` and `/etc/powerstatus` is discouraged. Someone wanting to interact with init should use the `/run/initctl` control channel - see the source code of the sysvinit package for more documentation about this.

I've looked at the [source](https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/sysvinit) hosted by gnu.org but I've not seen any examples of anything using this *new fangled* interface to tell `init` things.

Interestingly, the hydra that is `systemd` does try to replicate this interface as I think somethings do not like it not being around but I have not found something that actually uses it.  Is there such a thing? I'd expect some UPS related software to, e.g. `nut` but I don't think it does...

*This question, although it mentions "Raspberry Pi" is not intended to be specific to that platform or the distributions like Raspbian that run on it.*

These questions and their answers were quite enlightening on filling in some related details:

- [Linux - IPC with init](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191726/linux-ipc-with-init/191875#191875)
- [shutdown-run-initctl-no-such-file-or-directory](https://superuser.com/questions/886825/shutdown-run-initctl-no-such-file-or-directory)

Edit: at least one of the above Q&A also indicated why some people have /dev/initctl and others /run/initctl - which was something I didn't realise (it was a Debian thing).

Answer (score 2):

I believe `reboot` uses it.
Do an `strace` of `reboot`:

```
# strace -s 128 -f reboot
```

Somewhere towards the bottom I see:

```
open("/dev/initctl", O_WRONLY)          = 3
write(3, "i\31\t\3\6\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0INIT_HALT\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
close(3)

...

open("/dev/initctl", O_WRONLY)          = 3
write(3, "i\31\t\3\1\0\0\0006\0\0\0\5\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
close(3)
```

Answer (score 1):

On Debian the following packages use /run/initctl: systemd, libvirt, sysvinit, refpolicy, gradm2.  (from https://codesearch.debian.net/ ).

I think it is the normal way to tell init to change runlevel.

Comment: That [codesearch](https://codesearch.debian.net/) link does look useful for Debian users.  I am not altogether convinced that all of those *use* it - I think some (`systemd` ?) just make sure that the FIFO *exists* (for compatibility purposes!)- I recall somewhere that *bad things* happen if it isn't around (though that could just be that `init` itself gets really uptight if the thing does not exist and cannot be *created* by it) - guess I have some code reading to do...