# Telinit command not works

Tags: runlevel

I wasn't aware of the telinit command and I've tried to use it without any good result.

Below my command

```
telinit 1
```

I obtain the following error:

```
timeout opening/witing control channel /dev/initctl
```

The obtained strace doesn't help me

```
...
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {0x11de0, [], 0x4000000 /* SA_??? */}, NULL, 8) = 0
setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, {it_interval={0, 0}, it_value={3, 0}}, {it_interval={0, 0}, it_value={0, 0}}) = 0
open("/dev/initctl", O_WRONLY)          = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
--- SIGALRM {si_signo=SIGALRM, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
sigreturn() (mask [QUIT])               = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
write(2, "telinit: ", 9telinit: )                = 9
write(2, "timeout opening/writing control "..., 53timeout opening/writing control channel /dev/initctl
) = 53
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

What does it mean?

Comment: If you are running systemd on your system, use systemctl get-default and systemctl set-default to change run levels. Run levels that can be set can be seen in usr/lib/systemd/system/.

Comment: I'm not using systemd (I'm using busybox init). Furthermore my primary goal is to be able to enter in single user mode

Comment: If the questioner were running systemd the right thing to do would be to [forget about runlevels](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/394238/5132).

Comment: Thanks for the link but, as written, systemd supports a sort of backward compatibility and hence some programs like telinit still work well. In my case I'm using the busybox init and it doesn't have the runlevel concept. I don't think it is correlated to my error but I'm not so expert and I need advices from someone more expert than me

Answer (score 0):

## Forget about runlevels.

Yes, it the same answer as for systemd.

BusyBox's own `init` program does not have a concept of runlevels in the first place.  This is in [the BusyBox doco](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/init/init.c#n1273).  There *is no* run level 1 to command changing to.  Using `telinit` with actual BusyBox `init` is simply wrong.

When using `telinit` with some *other* toolset's system manager running as process #1, it is still overwhelmingly wrong.  On systemd operating systems, runlevels are "obsolete"; they do not exist on systems managed by many other toolsets (from the nosh `system-manager` through Gerrit Pape's `runit-init` to [initNG](http://initng.org/)); and it is only really van Smoorenburg `init`, Joachim Nilsson's [`finit`](http://troglobit.com/projects/finit/) and Upstart that have the mechanism at all.

Note that the `telinit` program has to match the toolset that is actually being used at the time for the system-manager program.  There are lots of `telinit` programs from different toolsets.  Some expect a FIFO in `/dev/initctl`.  Some expect a FIFO in `/run/initctl`.  Some speak different protocols over their FIFOs, and the van Smoorenburg `init` protocol is considered private anyway by its developers.  Many do not even use a FIFO at all and are shims around mechanisms native to the toolset, such as the nosh `telinit` which is a shim around `system-control`, the Upstart `telinit` which emits Upstart events, and the systemd `telinit` which is its `systemctl` program by another name.  And even for those that do use a FIFO there's the matter of there needing to be a server, which *also* has to match the running system manager, running and listening on those FIFOs.

All of this to enable people to preserve the learned habits of running a `telinit` command.

Forget about runlevels, and if you have not already got into the habit of using `telinit` (or, worse, `init` as a command), it is better not to learn it in the first place.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015).  [*`/etc/inittab` is a thing of the past.*](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/inittab-is-history.html).  Frequently Given Answers.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/191875/5132
- https://superuser.com/a/888936/38062
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196197/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196014/5132
- Roger Leigh (2012-02-01). *[systemd: `/dev/initctl` has moved to `/run/initctl`](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=657990#57)*.  Debian Bug #657990.
- Joachim Nilsson.  ["Rebooting & Halting"](https://github.com/troglobit/finit/blob/master/README.md#user-content-rebooting--halting)  finit.
- Scott James Remnant (2009).  [`telinit`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/telinit.8.html).  Upstart user manual.  Ubuntu.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018).  [`telinit`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/telinit.html). *nosh Guide*. Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018).  [`init`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/init.html). *nosh Guide*. Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018).  [`initctl-read`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/initctl-read.html). *nosh Guide*. Softwares.
- Lennart Poettering et al. (2017).  [`telinit`](https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/telinit.html).  systemd user manual.  freedesktop.org.