# init: must be run as PID 1

Tags: process, init

Recently encountered a problem: when entering `init 1`, it gives an error: `init: must be run as PID 1`. I Entering `ps` and it turns out that `/sbin/init` has PID *1*. How now can I use `init`?

Comment: *"use `init`"* to do what, exactly?

Comment: Have you tried `telinit`? systemd manual says that its `init` will forward to `telinit` if PID is not 1 (not being init, but being used to message init).

Comment: `command not found: telinit`

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: I'm running Alpine linux

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Switch system to a single-user mode

Comment: try `rc single` if alpine is still using openrc that might work, ... https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux_Init_System

Comment: Thanks, it's working

Comment: A related question, for a systemd operating system, is https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/389289/5132 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `init`.  It is the wrong program for the job.

You need to un-learn the idea that `init` can be invoked as a normal command.  The `init` programs where this is/was true are not the `init` program that you have.  There are 4 `init` programs where one can invoke it as a normal command, and you are not using any of them.  Rather, you are using BusyBox `init`, which if it detects that it has been invoked as anything other than process #1 on the system, prints that message and exits.  It has no functionality for other than as process #1.

There is no `telinit` in BusyBox, either.  Its `init` does not have a client/server interface over a FIFO.

To shut down, you must do something that eventually results in `SIGPWR`, `SIGUSR1`, `SIGUSR2`, or `SIGTERM` being sent to process #1.  Note that, as with other system management toolsets, "single-user mode" (a misnomer since 1995) is not a shutdown target.  One does not shut down to such a mode, and BusyBox `init` is not actually involved in enacting such a mode.

Rather, in systems using OpenRC on top of BusyBox `init`, this is a mode that is entirely the province of OpenRC mechanisms.  `openrc single` changes to the mis-named "single" mode.  (Using OpenRC's *own* `init`, which is not the case for you, there is a `shutdown` command that talks to it.  But that's just [a quite roundabout way](https://github.com/OpenRC/openrc/blob/master/src/rc/openrc-init.c#L182) of running `openrc single`, it turns out.)

[Alpine Linux is documenting](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux_Init_System) an outdated OpenRC, note.  OpenRC itself does not have a `single` directory any more.  [That was removed in 2019](https://github.com/OpenRC/openrc/commit/5c5129b534bd8a0ebd0e525c87241d6c6ef0ec8c).  Furthermore, [the `rc` command changed to `openrc` in 2014](https://github.com/OpenRC/openrc/commit/87884db66767eba6317b506a4d7270dd22721831).

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/463504/5132